# Why multiple useEffect not override each other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I am new to lifecycle hooks, Pardon me if this is very basic and understood,  but I don't understand So how come all different `useEffect` methods are called differently?

I know that JavaScript doesn't supports function overLoading.

So if I write this,

```
add(){
  console.log("asd")
}
add(c){
console.log("asdfgh");
}
add();//asdfgh
```

this will print `asdfgh`, even if its called without arguments,

Then how come all useEffect functions gets executed even when they have same name?

Answer (score 2):

In your example code, you are defining functions in the first two calls, rather than using them. When you use multiple `useEffect`s, you are calling `useEffect( myEffectFunction )` multiple times. It is analogous to your code being written like this:

```
function add(a, b){
  console.log(a + b)
}
add( 3, 5);// Calling your function the first time.
add( 1, 2);// Calling your function the second time.
```

Note that this isn't structurally different from the below code, which is how you use `useEffect` in a functional component--you aren't redefining `useEffect`, you are just calling `useEffect` twice, with different parameters.

```
function MyFirstEffect(){
  ...
}
function MySecondEffect(){
  ...
}
useEffect( myFirstEffect, [] ) // Calling useEffect once.
useEffect( mySecondEffect, [] ) // Calling useEffect a second time.
```

It may be helpful to review the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) docs; you can see that in the documentation example, a function is defined inside of `useEffect`'s parameter, but `useEffect` itself is just a function that is being called.

Update based on comments:

Comment: My question is even if i define multiple useEffect every useeffect gets called. But when I define same function name, multiple time, only a single function gets called. Why so?

Comment: @Aishwarya This answer already explains that. Method definitions in a class are completely different from function calls within another function.

Comment: @Aishwarya I've added some more explanation, does that help?